# API Error Code: 1383133 - payments

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Currently have an app in sandbox mode and have myself set as a test user for payments. When I try to process a payment, I send the following object:

```
{
  action: "purchaseitem",
  method: "pay",
  product: "<example>.com/og/200-coins.html",
  quantity: 200,
  quantity_max: 250,
  quantity_min: 150,
  request_id: "36"
}
```

And I'm getting the following response:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 1383133
API Error Description: app account id is 0. aid: 269576253216657
```

I've tried looking up the 1383133 error code but can't find any reference to it anywhere.

Anyone have a clue what could be going on here?

Comment: Should note, the foo.com is (obviously?) a stand in for the question only...

Comment: It sounds like your app has no payments info saved - is that accurate?

Comment: Yeah, Igy, that was it. It had payments info entered, and I thought I had saved it, but the lack of realtime update subscriptions was preventing it from actually being saved. I built that in and validated it and it's all good now. 

You want to put an answer in so I can accept it? Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason you'd see this error message is if the app ID opening the payments dialog hasn't got a company associated with it / there's no payout information saved - once that's saved this message should go away